# BasicNameValuePair (String, java.lang.String) in BasicNameValuePair cannot be applied

Tags: java, mysql, date

I am currently using this code to store two strings(newCategory & reportDate) in a database:

```
String newCategory = spinnerFood.getSelectedItem().toString();

            // Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting
            // the string representation of date (month/day/year)
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            // Get the date today using Calendar object.
            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            // Using DateFormat format method we can create a string
            // representation of a date with the defined format.
            String reportDate = df.format(today);

            // Preparing post params
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", newCategory));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dtime", reportDate));

            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();

            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_NEW_CATEGORY,
                    ServiceHandler.POST, params);
```

This stores the name string successfully. But the date and time data in the database contains the value:

`0000-00-00 00:00:00`

If I change the date string to a date/time format like so:

```
df.format(today);

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dtime", today));
```

I get the error:

BasicNameValuePair      (String, java.lang.String) in BasicNameValuePair cannot be applied

to (String, java.util.date)

Could someone inform me how I could store a date and time value to a database?

Comment: `Timestamp` to store both date and time.

Comment: How would I go about using Timestamp in this scenario?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: Invalid `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` values are converted to the `zero` value of the appropriate type. Like above as you said. @Cillin

Comment: Ok. But what is rs and index representing in this code: `java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp(index);//now retrieve here` Sorry im new to java..

Comment: here example purpose I'm giving how to retrieve datetime from db. i'm using single statement. its not complete code. `rs` is `ResultSet` object and `index` is an `int` value. Its a part of our `jdbc` code.

Comment: Ok thanks for that information. But when I replaced your code with mine and changed the column to Timestamp datatype it didnt seem to work. Im still getting the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in my database..

Comment: which date format are you using. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or any other. Because its worked for me. if you are getting all `0`means invalid format. @Cillin

Comment: Yes I am using that format. I will look into using a str_to_date function in my myphp file.

Comment: try without using any function. means without `str_to_date`. it will works. I'm directly storing to db as string only. I didn't perform any other conversions. But in `php` I didn't know.

Comment: which format are you using with `str_to_date`. @Cillin

Comment: I haven'y done it yet because I don't think it will work. Str_to_date converts only the date and not the time as far as I know..

Comment: without using `str_to_date` it worked for me. see formats of `str_to_date` http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you want to make a app that connects to a database and stores the current time, then you are better off making a Timestamp column in your sql table and have its value as CURRENT_TIME. You don't actually need to get the current time in your program and then send it to your table. You can just send whatever data you need to the table, then this Timestamp column will store the current time of which you sent that data to the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);//current date and time here, '2015-07-17 18:38:46'

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dtime", currentTime));//now pass here
```

Now store this value to `mysql` db whose column type `timestamp`. 
Now use `jdbc` code here to retrieve data from db.

```
  java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp(index);//now retrieve here
```

[For more?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the date and time to `params` as the formatted string

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dtime", reportDate));
```

Your code which handles the db calls would then use the mysql function `STR_TO_DATE(...)` to format the string into the DateTime required.